# Why CodeIgniter's Curl library slower than using Curl in plain PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, performance

Recently I moved my scraping code with Curl to CodeIgniter. I'm using Curl CI library from http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-curl. I put the scraping process in a controller and then I found the execution time of my scraping is slower than the one I built in plain PHP.

It took 12 seconds for CodeIgniter to output the result, whereas it only takes 6 seconds in plain PHP. Both are including the parsing process with the HTML DOM parser.

Here's my Curl code in CodeIgniter:

```
function curl($url, $postdata=false)
{
  $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";

  $this->curl->create($url);
  $this->curl->ssl(false);
  $options = array(
    'URL'             => $url,
    'HEADER'          => 0,
    'AUTOREFERER'     => true,
    'FOLLOWLOCATION'  => true,
    'TIMEOUT'         => 60,
    'RETURNTRANSFER'  => 1,
    'USERAGENT'       => $agent,
    'COOKIEJAR'       => dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt",
    'COOKIEFILE'      => dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt",
  );

  if($postdata)
  {
    $this->curl->post($postdata, $options);
  }
  else
  {
    $this->curl->options($options);
  }

  return $this->curl->execute();
}
```

non codeigniter (plain php) code :

function curl($url ,$binary=false,$post=false,$cookie =false ){

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);



    if($cookie){


        $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");

    }


    if($binary)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);


    if($post){


        foreach($post as $key=>$value) 
            { 
        $post_array_string1 .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
        }
        $post_array_string1 = rtrim($post_array_string1,'&');

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array_string1);
    }

        return  curl_exec ($ch);
```

}

Does anyone know why this CodeIgniter Curl is slower??  or maybe it's because the simple_html_dom parser??

Comment: Can you post your non-codeigniter code so I can test it myself?

Comment: Do you test on local machine? Do you send same data with same size through curl and codeigniter's curl? Do you test with 100 connections?

Comment: yes I tested on localhost xampp with same data and size , what do you mean test by 100 connections?

Comment: non codeigniter code posted ...could it be the html parsing process ?? Im using simple_html_dom.php both on plain php and codeigniter

Comment: is 12 second time was just for single parse or did you do it for batch? Object wrappers and magic method usage (__call here) do have some overhead but double time seems unexpected.

Comment: what do you mean by single parse??

Comment: all guys above meant you have to run some big batch of loads to say the time is different for these 2 approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I know the exact answer for this, but I have a few observations about Curl & CI as I use it extensively.

1. Check for the state of DNS caches/queries.

I noticed a substantial speedup when code was uploaded to a hosted staging server from my dev desktop.  It was traced to a DNS issue that was solved by rebooting a bastion host...  You can sometimes check this by using IP addresses instead of hostnames.

1. Phil's 'library' is really just a wrapper.

All he's really done is map CI-style functions to the PHP Curl library.  There's almost nothing else going on.  I spent some time poking around (I forget why) and it was really unremarkable.  That said, there may well be some general CI overhead - you might see what happens in another similar framework (Fuel, Kohana, Laravel, etc).

1. Check your reverse lookup.

Some API's do reverse DNS checks as part of their security scanning.  Sometimes hostnames or other headers are badly set in buried configs and can cause real headaches.

1. Use Chrome's Postman extension to debug REST APIs.

No comment, it's brilliant - https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/wiki and you have fine grained control of the 'conversation'.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to know more about the CI Library and if it is doing any extra tasks on the gathered data but I would try naming your method to something other than the library name. I have had issues where with the Facebook library, calling it in a method named facebook caused problems. $this->curl could be ambiguous to if you are talking about the library or the method.

Also, try adding the debug profiler and see what it comes up with. Add this either in the construct or the method:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```